# Jooq transactions: connections are not released to pool, if exception thrown in transaction

Tags: transactions, kotlin, jooq

I'm using HikariCP with Jooq. 
The code: 
*In Kotlin:

```
//dataSource is from Hikari
DSL.using(dataSource, sqlDialect).transaction {
     config ->
     //in create it simply calls dsl.insertInto .... 
     UserRepo.create(User(name="joe"), DSL.using(config))
     UserRepo.create(User(name="foo"), DSL.using(config))

}
```

And everything runs ok.

But if I throw in block, the connections are not closed (released) (though the transaction is rolled back).

UPDATE:

I'm new to Java so it was my fault. In test, I used to throw Kotlin's `Throwable` (not the `Exception`), which was not correctly handled by Java part of the code.

Everything works as expected with regular Exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, given your question edit, jOOQ internally catches only `Exception` subtypes, not `Throwable` subtypes in order to influence the transaction management. In [`DefaultDSLContext.transactionResult0()`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/version-3.9.6/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/DefaultDSLContext.java#L474), you can see the following code (taken form version 3.9.6, shortened for this question):

```
try {
    provider.begin(ctx);
    result = transactional.run(ctx.configuration());
    provider.commit(ctx);
}
catch (Exception cause) { // <-- This is the problem
    ctx.cause(cause);
    provider.rollback(ctx);

    if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
        throw (RuntimeException) cause;
    }
    else {
        throw new DataAccessException("Rollback caused", cause);
    }
}
```

As you can see, while there is a distinction between checked and unchecked *exceptions* there's no distinction between `Exception` and `Throwable`.

#### Rationale, in Java vs Kotlin / Scala

Historically, in Java, no one really creates `Throwable` subtypes. That type only exists as a common super type for `Exception` and `Error`. So, the assumption is that a `Throwable` is either of the above, and `Error` types usually shouldn't be caught by any client / library code.

That assumption is invalidated by languages like Kotlin and Scala, which do not inherit this, admittedly a bit weird API design from early Java days. There's no reason why a user-defined exception shouldn't directly extend `Throwable`. Unfortunately, the status quo means you cannot use throwables, you have to throw exceptions.

#### Bug

This is certainly a bug in jOOQ and should be fixed:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6608

As it is somewhat backwards-incompatible in terms of behaviour, it will only be fixed in a minor release, i.e. 3.10